# Flash Pro Desktop AIR App into Flash Builder

Tags: air, flash-builder, desktop-application, flash-cs6

I would like to use the Flash Builder Profiler to analyse the performance of an AIR desktop application that ive built using Flash Professional..

The available help/resources for FlashBuilder show how to set up an existing FlashProfessional project inside FB but theres no mention of what to do if its an Air app.

Basically it defaults it to a Web Application.

Ive tried creating a new Desktop Application profile config but it says 'Project must be an Adobe AIR desktop project'.  Looking at the project properties under the ActionScript Compiler section it does look to be targeting AIR SDK.

Really stumped with this and so any help appreciated.

Comment: Hey there - ever find a solution for this? I've been stuck on the same problem for days. -tx.

Comment: @TOMATO As I mentioned in my answer, use Adobe Scout. It's what it's made for. It's far easier to use and offers a ton more profiling/benchmarking features that Flash Builder doesn't. We begged Adobe for a decent tool and they provided.

Answer (score -1):

If you need to profile your app, **ignore** anything from Flash Builder or Flash Pro or Flash Develop or IntelliJ or any other IDE. Instead, use [Adobe Scout](http://gaming.adobe.com/technologies/scout/). Adobe built Scout purposefully for Flash profiling, specifically with AIR apps and games in mind. The app is very powerful and should be everything you should ever need to analyze your app. The profilers provided by the IDEs do not even compare, especially when you turn on advanced-telemetry